# Jenkins pipeline script returned exit code 3

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

While using parallel pipeline getting exit code 3 in shell script.

```
stage('Core:Restart')
{ agent { label "master" } 
    steps { 
        wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: "${password}"]]]) 
        { sh label: '', 
            script: '''#!/bin/bash
            if [[ -z ${CORE_BRANCH} ]] then
                echo "You have entered empty branch for CORE Module" 
            else
                for ip in ${CORE_SERVER_IP//,/ }; do 
                    echo "$ip" 
                    sshpass -p $password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt ${USER}@${ip} <<EOF
                        set -e 
                        sudo -i
                        set -e 
                        /etc/init.d/tomcat status 
                        exit 0 
                        exit 0 
EOF 
                done
            fi''' 
        } 
    } 
}
```

sharing below snapshot as additional reference.
[Jenkins option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze51J.png)

Comment: Share your pipeline script. Never post a picture of text; it doea not add value and can't be searched.

Comment: Below is the stage which return exit code 3                                  
stage('Core:Restart') {
agent {
label "master"
}
steps {
wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: "${password}"]]]) {
sh label: '', script: '''#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z ${CORE_BRANCH} ]]
then
echo "You have entered empty branch for CORE Module"
else
for ip in ${CORE_SERVER_IP//,/ }; do
echo "$ip"
sshpass -p $password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt ${USER}@${ip} <<EOF
set -e
sudo -i
set -e
/etc/init.d/tomcat status
exit 0
exit 0
EOF
done
fi'''
}
}
}

Comment: I have added the code segment to the post. seems you might have duplicate commands or I formatted it wrong. I am going to guess "3" is the [return value from sshpass](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sshpass.1.html#return%20values). I'd try using `#!/bin/bash -eu` and then add ` -x ` , and see where it's failing. Also, can't you simply `sudo service tomcat status`  and then `echo $?`, which gives you the [real return code](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/iniscrptact.html), which might also be "3"

Comment: Thanks Lan W, might be tomcat is not running due to that , it returning error code 3.  I will modify and will update same.